# Importing Lines of Code from Another Notebook

Tags: import, notebooks

I'm trying to access lines of code from another Mathematica notebook using NotebookImport

```
NotebookImport[FileNameJoin@{NotebookDirectory[], "QA.nb"}, _]
```

Stuff in Notebook that I'm importing from:
`F[x_]:=x^Sqrt[2]+1`
Trigonometry

My Output is :

```
{Cell[BoxData[
   RowBox[{RowBox[{"F", "[", "x_", "]"}], ":=", 
     RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["x", SqrtBox["2"]], "+", "1"}]}]], "Code",
   CellChangeTimes -> {{3.79913*10^9, 3.79913*10^9}}, 
  CellLabel -> "In[22]:=", 
  ExpressionUUID -> 
   "8583411c-4a4d-4f21-86d8-ebfb497b6dfc"], "Trigonometry", 
 HoldComplete[Null]}
```

Is there any command that would display simply the line of code or is there any way of simplifying the output to the original line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you assign your Output to `c`, then

```
Cases[Cases[c, e_Cell :> MakeExpression[e, StandardForm]], 
  ExpressionCell[line_, "Code", ___] :> 
   ToString[Unevaluated@line, InputForm], -1] // First
```

returns

```
"F[x_] := x^Sqrt[2] + 1"
```